# How to run Activity app cloased scenario in android

Tags: android, android-activity, broadcastreceiver

Anyone help me how to solve this issue? please. The above code app open scenario is working fine ReminderAlertDialogActivity but the app closed scenarioReminderAlertDialogActivity not calling. i checked the Android 12 device

final private BroadcastReceiver reminderAlertReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {

```
    @Override
    public void onReceive(final Context context, final Intent intent) {

        Log.e("call_reminderxxx","@"+intent.getStringExtra("message"));
        String message = intent.getStringExtra("message");
        long time = intent.getLongExtra("time", System.currentTimeMillis());
        if (last_message.equals(message) && last_time == time) {
            return;
        }
        // To Avoid the RemainderAlertDialogActivity To be started multiple
        // time, in case of SameTime reminders
        if (System.currentTimeMillis() - last_reminder_alert_at < 2 * SECONDS) {
            DELAY_TIME_OUT = 5000;// Delay By 5 Seconds
        } else {
            DELAY_TIME_OUT = 0;
        }


        // Perform your desired actions here with the provided data
        Log.e("MyBroadcastReceiver", "Received message: " + message);
        Log.e("MyBroadcastReceiver", "Received time: " + time);


        // Start the JobIntentService
      //  MyJobIntentService.enqueueWork(context, intent);
        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                // Start the background service to execute your desired code

                Log.e("alaramrunning","@"+intent.getStringExtra("message"));
                try {
                    // This method will be executed once the timer is over
                    
                        // create ReminderAlertDialogActivity
                        Log.e("callvvvvv","@first");
                        last_reminder_alert_at = System.currentTimeMillis();
                        last_message = intent.getStringExtra("message");
                        last_time = intent.getLongExtra("time", System.currentTimeMillis());
                        Intent remainderIntent = new Intent(context, ReminderAlertDialogActivity.class);
                        remainderIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                        remainderIntent.putExtra("msg", intent.getStringExtra("message"));
                        remainderIntent.putExtra("date", intent.getLongExtra("time", System.currentTimeMillis()));
                        startActivity(remainderIntent);
                   
                }catch (Exception e)
                {
                    Log.e("errrrrrrr","@"+"#"+e.toString());
                }

                Log.e("alaramrunningzzz","@"+"run");
            }
        }, DELAY_TIME_OUT);

    }
};
```